# Converting a Map to a List

Tags: java, list, collections, dictionary, arraylist

Is there anyone who knows how to convert a Map to a List

I found here something like this :

```
List<Value> list = new ArrayList<Value>(map.values());
```

But this is going to store just the value of the Map to the List

What I want to do is : copy the Key & the Value to the List

So, do you know how to achieve this ?

Comment: Maps and Lists are different data structures, how would you want to combine the map keys and values into the list?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "copy the key and the value to the list"?

Comment: why do you want to do this? They are different data structures and are used for different purposes.

Comment: I have a `Map<String, String>` and a `List<String>` so I want to do like the example showed in the post but by copying both (key & value)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will give you a List of the Map entries:

```
List<Map.Entry<Key, Value>> list = 
    new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Key, Value>>(map.entrySet());
```

FYI, entries have a `getKey()` and a `getValue()` method.

Answer (score 3):

One way you can do is Create a List with adding all the keys like :

```
List list = new ArrayList(map.keySet());
```

Then add all the values like :

```
 list.addAll(map.values);
```

And then probably you have to access with index like:
if map size is 10 , you know that you have 20 elements in the list. 
So you have to write a logic to access the key-value from the list with proper calculation of index  like: size/2 something like that. 
I am not sure if that helps what your requirement is.

Answer (score 2):

Try storing the [`Map.Entry`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)s of the `map`:

```
new ArrayList<Entry<Key, Value>>(map.entrySet());
```

---

**Example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    map.put("Hello", 0);
    map.put("World!", 1);

    ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>> list =
        new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet());

    System.out.println(list.get(0).getKey() + " -> " + list.get(0).getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both @Bohemian and @dacwe are right. I'd say moreover: in most cases you do not have to create your own list. Just use `map.entrySet()`.  It returns Set, but Set is just a Collection that allows iterating over its elements. Iterating is enough in 95% of cases.